# Compatibility of Rails 4 engine with Rails 3 or higher version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I need to develop a rails app. I am confused on which version should I use for develop 4.2 or 3.2. 
If I develop on Rails 4.2 will it be compatible with Rails 3 or higher version because we are developing the app as a product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well your issue. Are you developing from scratch? Then you should use the last stable version (4.2) because you will have support for a longer time. Anything that you code and test will work.

Version problems come when you **already** have some code and want to update your Rails version while keeping old code, example: You have an old Rails 3 app and for some reason you want to migrate it to Rails 4.

Even then, if you have different existing rails apps in your server, you can use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to have them all living at the same time.

It seems there are some concepts missing here: The main problem you have is with your Gemfile and probably some of the new syntax introduced in Rails 4. You just shouldn't be moving code between Rails app which have different versions, that's all.

Comment: Actually we are developing new product from scratch as engine like spree or devise.  I developed dummy engine on rails 4.2 and tried to use on 3.2 but giving gem dependency issues.

In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 3.2.16) ruby depends on
      railties (3.2.16)

Comment: But why are you trying to use it somewhere else? That is a problem in your Gemfile. Your Gemfile usually contains the Rails version you are going to have in your app, and it's fixed. So if you move the code from your 4.2 app to a Rails 3 app for sure there will be problems. You can stick to your Rails 4 app or develop in the Rails 3.2 app, but don't move code from one to another if you want to avoid version problems.

Comment: For example , if our client already developed application in 3.2 and He wants to use our engine then its not compatible. We want to develop engine which support for 3.2 and higher version.

Comment: In that case what you need to do is developing the app in Rails 3.2 or have your client's application upgraded to Rails 4. You can try to use non-breaking syntax but eventually you will run into bugs as that is not the point of Rails versions.